# Understanding limit superior of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $a(n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R$. The following are equivalent:

1. $\limsup a(n) = A$;
2. For every $A' > A$, $a(n) < A'$
   for all but **finitely** many $n$; for every $A'' < A$, $a(n) > A''$ for
   **infinitely** many $n$.

So, we have limit superior $A$. As $A'>A$ shouldn't $a(n)  < A'$ for **infinitely** many $n$? As $A'' < A$, $a(n) > A''$ for **infinitely** many $n$? Does the statement say that if we have a real number that is more than a limit superior then all the sequence for infinitely (in the statement it says finitely) many $n$ are less than that number. And if we have a number that is less than a limit superior then the sequences for infinitely many $n$ are more than that number. What does it mean by equivalence, I can't see any equivalence here.There are only inequalities. Thank you.

Comment: How do you *define* $\limsup$?

Comment: Did you perhaps mis-read "all but finitely many" as  "finitely many" in item 2?

Comment: what is the difference between these two? so, they are not the same? thanks.

Comment: what's A'?what's A''?

Comment: I think A' and A'' are real numbers. there is no other information about the proposition

Answer (score 0):

**just small example**

$$a (n)=(-1)^n $$
$$\limsup a_n=1$$

$$b_n=\sin(n\frac {\pi}{3}) $$

$$\limsup b_n=\frac {\sqrt {3}}{2}$$

Comment: The OP asked for examples.